# Null check for a single id parameter on the Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

In a Spring Boot Controller, I am trying to validate an id field in `Long` type as shown below:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getById(@PathVariable @NotNull Long id) {
    final EmployeeResponse response = employeeService.getById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(...);
}
```

But when I try to send request with null id parameter, ı get the following error:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: ":id""

I also tried using `long` and `@Valid` annotation, but does not make any sense and a similar error is encountered. So, is it possible to validate id parameter of the request?

Comment: the problem doesn't seem to be the validation, but rather the datatype and content you send as param. "" is an empty String, which can not be cast to a numerical type. What you can try, is to make the parameter a String, verify it's not empty in the method itself, and after that, cast it to a Long

Comment: Actually I use Postman and normally I want to use default settings for Postman side. But, in this case, I think there is not an easy approach to solve this problem by using some validation or annotation). I do not want to make my Controller dirty with unnecessary validations and for this reason would like to solve the problem with an annotation. Any example please?

Comment: The problem is that the system seems to recognize it as an empty String. an empty String will not trigger a null validation.

Comment: Then, can we say that there is no need to validate this even for a best practices?

Comment: you can adopt that, but what are you going to do if they pass "yabbadabbadoo" as parameter?

Comment: Good point ("yabbadabbadoo"). At this stage, I am wondering what Java Developers normally do for this situations? Is there anything that I should follow?

Comment: it depends on the situation. is the path param for you always the last part of the endpoint? if so, mark it as not required, and check whether it is present within the method. you shouldn't worry to much about adding a line of code. The first (and most important) concern is functioning code, and if that requires an additional line of code, you should add it

Comment: Show exactly what you mean by "send request with null id parameter". Presumably, just `http://myhost/context-root/` ?

Comment: @dbreaux You do not need to force your brain too much. Just keep id field null when sending request on Postman.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that showing the actual URL you're hitting would make your question more clear. It's not really about Postman, but about what kind of URL you're trying to handle or ignore. Postman is just one tool people might or might not use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using

```
@PathVariable(...)
```

They cannot be optional. This reflects the nature of path variables - it doesn't really make sense for them to be null. REST-style URLs always need the full URL path. If you have an optional component, consider use

```
@RequestParam(...)
```

instead.

You can use
`@NotNull`
in your entities itself.

Comment: Finally a good explanation, thanks a lot. Then, if I want to use `@PathVariable`, I can use primitive and no need to use Object type for id field. Similarly, I think it would be useful to use Object types in DTO s for validation purposes. Right?

Comment: And it will not matter if you use Long or long you can use anything.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it make sense to have @PathVariable  as @NotNull?
Because it's different url if it's null. So you could handle that with other endpoint @GetMapping("/")

Comment: Thanks, voted up. But I do not want a new endpoint.

Comment: It wouldn't be a new endpoint, just a new method to handle the path when there is no id specified.

Comment: Well I think 404 not found response would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which I pretty much always use for path & normal params in the URL, is the following: Just use `String` for every parameter.

As URL is easily manipulable by any user, they can e.g. just enter ".../sos" instead of a valid number and you'll receive the same error.

Why? Everything in a URL is a String. When Spring Boot notices the controller accepting a Long as a parameter, it tries to parse it by itself.

This won't happen if you use a String, as previously mentioned: everything in the URL already is a String and SB won't need to parse it to any other datatype.

I'd recommend you to just have String parameters in your method aswell and then just do the parsing/converting manually via `.getById(Long.parseLong(id));`.

This way you can e.g. catch any parse exception and return an appropriate error message.

Comment: Actually `@PathVariable` seems more professional with a clear parameter url e.g. `/{id}`. Normally I would solve the problem easily by using `@requestParam`, but ı am trying to find a solution. On the other hand, `.getById(Long.parseLong(id))` would probably solves the problem, but is it a good approach or unnecessary?

Comment: IMO it's a good approach. If you want to further enhance your validation or as you mentioned in one of your comments "not bloat your controller", just make the service-method accept a String as well and do all the validation inside your service. If you don't want to bloat your service just add an additional ValidationService or sth. like that.

Comment: I do not know why, but Long.parseLong is not available in the method parameters. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @devx Long.parseLong is a basic and integral part of the Java language. What do you mean 'in the method parameters'?

Comment: Don't put Long.parseLong directly into the method-params... Use it like shown in the method-_call_

Comment: And then make the Controller method a garbage that is the last thing that I want.

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle bad URLs. If you don't care that somebody passing a non-long will get a default Spring error response - which _might_ reveal internal things about the app - like just the fact that it is using Spring - then explicitly handling the errors and controlling what they return would be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add values to **@GetMapping**, because URL will wait path with data, cuz data also means path. Also you need to add **@PathVariable(required = false)**, it means your address in mapping will not wait data, and can come **null** if you ust call ***"/"***, in your service you see null data for id, cuz calls another value for your path.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{id}", ""})
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getById(@PathVariable(required = false) Long id) {
    if (id == null) { // Do something when null
        }
        else {// do another thing
        }
        return "your data";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it makes completely ugly my method.

Comment: @devx no, it will not, because you don't need add new endpoint, you just add path to value and check data from PathVariable

Comment: Note the `required=false` part of this. If you want to accept URLs without the ID, say to return a non-default error, this would be useful. Otherwise Spring will just return its default 404 not found response if no ID is specified in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you check [this](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/rest-api-request-validation-examples)
especially sixth paragraph, where he explains which sort of constraints work for which datatypes.

Comment: Don't just post a link to somewhere else as an answer. Chances are that page will be removed/altered later on, and will be rendered useless as answer. You can link to it, but add all the relevant information in the answer as well

Comment: @Stultuske fair enough, Here is copypasta from that site.

Comment: don't forget to add the 'copy paste'

Comment: Ah, it's too long the point is DecimalMax, DecimalMin, Digits, Max, Min accept long. Not Null accepts anytype, but it works one layer later because the variable is in the path